# First Steps Towards a Chatroom

Tags: html, chatroom

I've been trying to figure out how to word this for ten minutes, so I just made an animation. This animation shows what it is I'm trying to code. I've already coded the layout and design, but I can't figure out how to make it actually function.

[Animation Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukxy0.gif)

I've been using Dreamweaver to write the code and Mozilla Thimble to upload it. I'm using HTML with a simple CSS stylesheet. I know how to use Javascript, but I haven't found any way to use it in this code.*

Is there any way to code it?

*Yes, I know that the `<script>` tag exists, but I can't find any way to apply it as a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please read the following in the help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: You might find some informative tutorials [around the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+chatroom+with+javascript). Maybe you can find a starting place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code for a basic HTML chatroom:

```js
<?
session_start();
 
function loginForm(){
    echo'
    <div id="loginform">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>
    </div>
    ';
}
 
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

```css
/* CSS Document */
body {
    font:12px arial;
    color: #222;
    text-align:center;
    padding:35px; }
  
form, p, span {
    margin:0;
    padding:0; }
  
input { font:12px arial; }
  
a {
    color:#0000FF;
    text-decoration:none; }
  
    a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
  
#wrapper, #loginform {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    background:#EBF4FB;
    width:504px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }
  
#loginform { padding-top:18px; }
  
    #loginform p { margin: 5px; }
  
#chatbox {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:270px;
    width:430px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow:auto; }
  
#usermsg {
    width:395px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }
  
#submit { width: 60px; }
  
.error { color: #ff0000; }
  
#menu { padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px; }
  
.welcome { float:left; }
  
.logout { float:right; }
  
.msgln { margin:0 0 2px 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
 
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
     
    <div id="chatbox"></div>
     
    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't work try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.container {
    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.darker {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.container img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container img.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right:0;
}

.time-right {
    float: right;
    color: #aaa;
}

.time-left {
    float: left;
    color: #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Chat Messages</h2>

<div class="container">
  <img src="/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <p>Hello. How are you today?</p>
  <span class="time-right">11:00</span>
</div>

<div class="container darker">
  <img src="/w3images/avatar_g2.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="right" style="width:100%;">
  <p>Hey! I'm fine. Thanks for asking!</p>
  <span class="time-left">11:01</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <p>Sweet! So, what do you wanna do today?</p>
  <span class="time-right">11:02</span>
</div>

<div class="container darker">
  <img src="/w3images/avatar_g2.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <p>Nah, I dunno. Play soccer.. or learn more coding perhaps?</p>
  <span class="time-left">11:05</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you would need to use javascript to add functionality to your chatroom by recording everything you type, and then using PHP and MySQL to add a database of users to talk to.

Maybe check out this video for starters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eDklLtzuB4

Its not the best chatroom but it will help you make one. :)